# Unable to import Spacy in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, spacy

I have tried by installing spacy in new virtual environment as well just in case if there are any module version clashes but still gives the same error upon doing the spacy import

`import spacy`

Also tried with downgrading of the spacy version to 2.2.2.

Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/catalogue.py", line 8, in <module>
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testUser/Desktop/ml/test-project/src/EmailParser.py", line 3, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._registry import registry
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/_registry.py", line 1, in <module>
    import catalogue
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/catalogue.py", line 10, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ._compat import (
  File "/Users/testUser/.virtualenvs/mlv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/_compat.py", line 115, in <module>
    email.message_from_string
AttributeError: module 'email' has no attribute 'message_from_string'
```

Comment: Do you have a file `email.py` in your project?

Comment: I do have a directory with the name email . Deleted it . 
Now it's working fine .
Is the email directory clashing with any module lookup ?
@FlyingTeller

Comment: Yes, the last line in the error shows that at some point a module `email` is being used. If you have a folder or file called that, it will clash